# Segmentation fault when importing ZBar on a BeagleBone black

Tags: python, beagleboneblack, zbar

Whenever I try to use ZBar on the BeagleBone Black, I get a segfault. Literally no other code running, just a simple import is enough to cause it.

```
    >>> import zbar
    Segmentation fault
```

That's literally all the code I have. I tried install zbar and all of its tools. `pip install zbar` etc, but I'm not sure what I could be doing to cause a segfault just from importing.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed Using this method:

`$ wget https://github.com/npinchot/zbar/archive/master.zip
$ unzip master.zip 
$ cd zbar-master
$ sudo python setup.py install`

Credit : [AhmedSamara Comment](https://github.com/IEEERobotics/bot/issues/431)